# Why does it appear a window in a flash when I use "call" in execjs, python?

Tags: javascript, python, execjs

I'm sure the problem happens here:

```
self.js_fun.call('myfunc')
```

and I have initialized `js_fun`:

```
self.js_fun = execjs.compile(f.read())
```

just as the title, there will always be a sudden window as it executes,
and disappeared as fast as a HK reporter

Lukily, I catched it anyway:

QAQ...`Failed to upload image; an error occured on the server`
OK then I paste the link here: [The image](https://imgchr.com/i/0gI9O0)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you possibly use a worse image hosting site with more ads?

Comment: Really...It's almost the best in my country...You know the GFW